# MVC Core 3.1 ForEach on view not updating values on controller

Tags: .net-core, foreach, controller

Please can someone advise as I have been going round in circles with this.  I have a view model which contains a list of my entity:

```
public List<Employee> EmployeeList{ get; set; }
```

This is being populated like so:

```
 var list = _context.Employees.Include(x => x.Office).Where(x => x.EmployeeID== id).ToList();

        var model = new EmployeeViewModel()
        {
            EmployeeList= list                       

        };
```

The view contains:

```
   @model MyProject.Models.EmployeeViewModel
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Form";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

     @foreach (var item in Model.EmployeeList)
        {

    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeID)
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Name) 
        }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("MyForm", "Employees", FormMethod.Post))
    {

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="SubmitAction" value="Submit">Update</button>
    }
```

I can see all the results but when I change a value on any rows editor from the view no changes are picked up in my controller:

```
      switch (submitAction)
            {
                case "Submit":
                    {

                        foreach (var Response in model.EmployeeList)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(Response);
                        }


                        return View(model);
                    }



            }
```

Please can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move foreach code to @using (Html.BeginForm) inside

**EDITED**

Index.cshtml

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="Index">
     @foreach (var item in Model.EmployeeList)
     {
          <input type="hidden" asp-for="item.EmployeeID" />
          <input type="text" asp-for="item.Name" />
     }
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="SubmitAction" value="Submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

EmployeeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(Employee emp)
{
     return View();
}
```

**EDITED 05 Feb 2020**

[image]

Change foreach to for loop.

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Index">
@{
    for (int i = 0; i <= Model.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Id" />
        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model[i].Name" />
        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model[i].EmailAddress" />
        <br /><br />
    }
}
<button>Save</button>
</form>
```

[image]

**Input email address.**

[image]

[image]

In your case, use @Model.EmployeeList[i].EmployeeID in view. and use Employee parameter in your controller.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, sadly this has not fixed it and i still am unable to see my changed values from the editors in the controller

Comment: Maybe you dump old mvc code. use .net core mvc code instead since you use .net core.

Comment: Edited post. Can check.

Comment: Thanks again for your input, sadly this has not worked as i am still not seeing the changed values from the view :(

Comment: Oh sorry, you try to change foreach to For loop. edited post. you can check.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience with this, changing that for each loop nailed it! i'm very grateful thank you!